# Intel Local APIC Spurious Interrupt

Tags: c, x86, interrupt-handling, apic

I'm developing now a code snippet that should enable\disable local APIC. I've seen in the Intel manual that I have to set a spurious interrupt vector prior to enabling LoAPIC. In the Intel Manual I see the following explanation:

> A special situation may occur when a processor raises its task priority to be greater than or equal to the level of the 
>   interrupt for which the processor INTR signal is currently being asserted. If at the time the INTA cycle is issued, the 
>   interrupt that was to be dispensed has become masked (programmed by software), the local APIC will deliver a 
>   spurious-interrupt vector. Dispensing the spurious-interrupt vector does not affect the ISR, so the handler for this 
>   vector should return without an EOI.
>   Blockquote

Can anyone please help me to understand what conditions lead the local APIC to issue a spurious interrupt?

Thanks in advance.